# UI-Router's resolve functions are only called once- even with reload option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In Angular ui router, when `$state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly");` is ran after `main.loadbalancer.readonly` has been previously activated, my resolve: {} is not being evaulauted/executed. The resolve is simply bypassed..I have verified this with the `console.log($state.current.data['deviceId']);` not showing.

```
angular.module("main.loadbalancer", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router"]).config(function($stateProvider) {
  return $stateProvider.state("main.loadbalancer", {
    url: "device/:id",
    views: {
      "content@": {
        templateUrl: "loadbalancer/loadbalancer.html",
        controller: "LoadBalancerCtrl"
      }
    }
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.vips", {
    resolve: {
        isDeviceReadOnly: function($state) {
          console.log($state.current.data['deviceId']);
          if (!$state.current.data['deviceId']) {
            console.log("pimp");
            $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly");
        } 
      } 
    },
    url: "/vips",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/vip-table.html",
    controller: "VipListCtrl"
  }).state("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {
    url: "/readonly",
    templateUrl: "loadbalancer/readonly.html",
    controller: "ReadonlyCtrl"
  });
});
```

---

Controller code:

```
  submit = function() {
    $state.current.data = { deviceId: false };
    return LoadBalancerSvc.searchDevice($scope.searchInput.value).get().then(function(lb) {
      console.log(lb.ha_status);
      if (lb.ha_status == "secondary") {
        console.log("hi");
        $state.current.data['deviceId'] = false;
        $state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly"); //WHEN THIS IS RAN A SECOND TIME
                                                   AFTER STATE HAS BEEN ACTIVE BEFORE
        $state.deviceReadonly = true
      } else {
        $state.current.data['deviceId'] = lb.id;
        $state.deviceReadonly = false;
        SearchSvc.updateDeviceNumber(lb.id);
        $state.go("main.loadbalancer.vips", {id: lb.id});
        console.log("bye");
      }
    });
  };
```

I can only guess that since `main.loadbalancer.vips` has been activated previously, then to ui router it means once resolved always resolved. How can I make it to where each time the state is activated with `$state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly")` resolve will be evaluated?

**Note**: I have also tried `$state.go("main.loadbalancer.readonly", { reload: true });` to no success.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 'transitionTo' works instead.

```
 if (lb.ha_status == "secondary") {
        $state.current.data['deviceId'] = false;
        $state.transitionTo("main.loadbalancer.readonly", {}, { reload: true });
        $state.deviceReadonly = true
      }
```